# В чем разница между __stdcall и _stdcall?

Tags: c++

В чем разница между `__stdcall` и `_stdcall`?

Comment: [What is the difference between __stdcall and _stdcal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12511451/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy, parlez russe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компилятор MSVC принимает и `_stdcall`, и `__stdcall`, одно или два подчеркивания.

Один символ `_` нужен, так как этого требует спецификация. Идентификаторы в глобальном неймспейсе, специфичные для вендора, или не стандартные ключевые слова должны иметь префикс - `_`.

Второй символ `_` нужен, потому что вендоры постоянно проигрывают битву с программистами, которые думают, что могут использовать префикс `_` для своих переменных в своем коде. А также, используется для других нестандартных ключевых слов вроде `__interface` и `__m128`. И в других компиляторах, например, `__attribute__` в gcc.

Очевидно, что нужно использовать версию из документации, с двумя подчеркиваниями.

<sub>[перевод ответа @HansPassant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12512546/2881286)</sub>